# Progress Bar not showing when setting visibility to VISIBLE

Tags: java, android, android-studio, progress-bar

I am creating a program that is supposed to show a progress bar when it is doing something in the background (using `AsyncTask`) and when the task finishes the progress bar goes and the result is shown.

I've included a progress bar in the `RecyclerView` but set it visibility to gone.
and in the AsyncTask PreExecute I set its visibility to `VISIBLE` and in `OnPostExecute` I set its visibility to `GONE` but when I run the application the progress bar doesn't show at all.

> I have included the XML :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<android.support.v4.widget.ContentLoadingProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/rv_progress_bar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:indeterminateTint="@color/plus_icon_color"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/train_rv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

> and the Java Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private RecyclerView mTrainsRv;
private TrainAdapter mTrainAdapter;
ArrayList<Train> trains = new ArrayList<>();
ProgressBar mRvProgress;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mRvProgress = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.rv_progress_bar);
    mTrainsRv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.train_rv);
    mTrainsRv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mTrainAdapter = new TrainAdapter(createDefaultTrains());
    mTrainsRv.setAdapter(mTrainAdapter);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            trains.add(new Train(4, "Berowra Platform 4", 12, "Late", "Beverly", "15:18"));
            mTrainAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}

private List<Train> createDefaultTrains() {
    trains.add(new Train(0, "Albion Park Platform 1", 3, "On Time", "Allawah", "14:11"));
    trains.add(new Train(1, "Arncliffe Platform 2", 4, "Late", "Central", "14:34"));
    trains.add(new Train(2, "Artarmion Platform 3", 7, "On Time", "Ashfield", "15:01"));
    trains.add(new Train(3, "Berowra Platform 4", 12, "Late", "Beverly", "15:18"));
    return trains;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_delete:
            trains.clear();
            mTrainAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_refresh:
            new RefreshProgressAsync().execute();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_quit:
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.quit_menu,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
private class RefreshProgressAsync extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Integer> {
private int mGenerated;

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int ran = 0;
        Random r = new Random();
        for(int i=0; i<trains.size(); i++) {
            int min = 1;
            int max = 20;
            ran = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
            mGenerated = ran;
        }
        return mGenerated;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mRvProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mTrainsRv.setAlpha(0);
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer arrivalTime) {
        super.onPostExecute(arrivalTime);
        for (int i=0; i<trains.size();i++){
            trains.get(i).setArrivalTime(arrivalTime);
        }
        mTrainAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mTrainsRv.setAlpha(1);
        mRvProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

I don't know why it isn't showing.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is behaving as expected. Purpose of `ContentLoadingProgressBar` is to show the progress only when necessary. If the operation take trivial amount of time, then the progress bar won't be shown. This is to avoid having flashing effect of progress bar, showing and disappearing in quick succession.

If you want to make it visible for testing purpose (I won't recommend in production code), then increase your sleep time to 10 seconds:

```
 @Override
  protected Integer doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ....
  }
```

Alternatively you can just use normal `ProgressBar`

Comment: Oh my god thanks! I am such an idiot I didn't notice I chose ContentLoadingProgressBar instead of normal progress bar because Android Studio give you suggestions and I might've chosen the wrong one! Thanks

Comment: Happens :-D If the answer was useful to you then remember to mark it as accepted so that others can benefit too! Enjoy coding